# How to automatically name a Wolfram Notebook after the first title line of code if present?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, cells, stylesheet, automation

I have a goal of somehow using Wolfram Mathematica's Notebook object functionality to program an initialization cell that will automatically save and name a new file after a title line of code formatted with Alt+1.
If there are multiple titles, I want to make name the file based on the first title.
If the document is not saved and one of the following happens:

- computer crashes and I have to restart
- Mathematica crashes and I have to reboot the Mathematica kernel
- my battery dies
- I  accidentally click don't save when I close the file

I would like to name the file based on whatever text is present in the title line, in a manner similar to how Google Docs and Microsoft Word automatically save a local copy of your document in AutoRecovery.